# Getting multiple LinkedIN members using API

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

Is it possible to get basic profile data from a list of people, using one app, akin to the [LinkedIN Member Profile Plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile)?

I want to get the basic profile information of about 40 people, for which the Profile Plugin is too slow, but I can only find how to get my own account information using the API.

I've gotten no further than the following:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json
```

Which is the only reference to basic profile information. But I need that from other users, instead of myself. I have found no references to it's possibilities since the [change in the API of may 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/todays-changes).

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734634/fastest-way-to-load-many-linkedin-profile-widgets)